# Связь приложения и сайта

Tags: php, java, android, mysql

Нужен совет. 
У меня есть сайт с бд MySql. Сейчас возникла идея создать android приложение, которое должно работать с информацией из этой бд MySql.

Я новичок в написание приложений и в java. Погуглив узнал, что можно сделать своего рода api на сайте к которому будет обращаться приложение и получать необходимые данные. Вопрос можно ли как-то напрямую из приложения обращаться к той же бд, что и сайт? Если нет, то в каком направлении мне надо копать?

Также буду благодарен, если кинете какие-нибудь полезные ссылки с примерами по моей теме.

Comment: api это и есть напрямую

Comment: т.е. сделать так, чтобы приложение направляло к сайту post запросы, а сайт в зависимости от запроса выдавал нужную мне информацию, так?

Comment: да (13 символов нужно...)

Comment: Еще есть вопрос, а не лучше тогда периодически, например один раз в день делать запрос к сайту и переписывать необходимые данные из бд сайта в бд приложения. А когда пользователь открывает приложение не делать запрос к сайту, а просто показывать ему данные из бд приложения. Приложение будет работать быстрей или нет?

Comment: Идея в том, что нужно сделать api (например, [rest](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST), которая и будет общаться с сервером. Если этот апи готов, то не будет иметь значения куда вы отправляете данные - на сайт, на телефон или на десктопное приложение. Хранить данные в локальной базе - не очень хорошая идея. Вы же не можете точно предугадать время изменения информации. Может получиться, что приложение обновляется раз в сутки, а через 10 минут после обновления данные в базе изменились, в итоге, пользователь видит неактуальную информацию.

Answer (score 1):

Вы конечно можете создать прямое подключение к удаленному серверу БД из вашего приложения, но так не стоит делать, тут подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470117/can-we-connect-remote-mysql-database-in-android-using-jdbc

Тут видео урок для решения вашей проблемы: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ptU_F3s30s